# Wifi not responding after a while - only on iPhone

Tags: ios

On my home network I have an ASUS-AC66U router (with the latest supported Merlin firmware) which also provides wifi (g and n band, 2.4GHz and 5GHz). The SSIDs of both wireless networks are the same. In addition, I have a pi.hole for DNS.

The problem I'm facing is that *only* on my iPhone 8 (iOS 13.3) I'm facing connection issues after a while. I have seen this in the Twitter, Reddit and Firefox app at least. I'm still connected to wifi, but the specific app can't get an connection (it just times out after a while). Changing to another app works, until that app also fails. Disconnecting and re-connecting to wifi always resolves the issue.

I'm not having this issue on my notebook, other mobile phones, or Surface Pro 4 tablet. Any wired devices also don't exhibit the problem.

What could cause these issues and how can I diagnose it?